# Is is a bad idea to have misc files sitting in bin directory

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

I have an assembly that contains a function that could be called from IIS or from a console app.

Because of this I have opted for the following to get the path:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

obviously this will return the bin directory in the case of the function being called from IIS.

I intend to create a txt file on this path. Is it such a bad idea to have text files sitting in the bin directory? Please give valid objections (if any) why this could cause problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Assembly.Location` can return surprising results, e.g. if shadow copying is turned on (for instance, when running through NUnit), or when running from a location not on the local file system (you can run .NET apps over HTTP).

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is a safer option, as it returns the original path prior to shadow copying (although in the case of HTTP deployment I think it returns the directory where `ieexec.exe` is located).

**The safest option** is to embed whatever data you need as a resource within the assembly, and use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` to access it at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You simply may not have enough permissions to write to this directory. Try using `TEMP` folder instead (think `Path.GetTempPath()`).

Comment: Ideally, using the System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() property.

Comment: Actually this is a great suggestion, only thing I don't like is that the temp directory is an obscure location and also subject to external forces (like admins cleaning it out)

Answer (score 2):

If you delete/copy/overwrite files in "bin" directory, the IIS will restart processes - because IIS thinks the application was changed, so new requestes should be proceeded with "new" appliaction.

So, **yes** it is bad idea.

Comment: indeed, so ANY change to any file in there will cause an IIS reset?

Comment: I thought it was just changes to DLLs and web.config

Comment: Any file causing IIS reset - because the assemblies can has any extensions or no extension or the file is not assembly, but can be part of application.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Robinson's got the right idea.

The only other thing I should say is if ASP.NET is writing the file, be careful with your threading code; maybe two requests for the same page will try to write the same file at the same time, so just be careful to lock your writes to the file.